# Changing the Java Icon and ToolBar Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons

I'm trying to change the Java icon and the title bar icon using this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    String title = Config.clientName + " Revision: " + Config.Revision + " Made by: " + Config.developerName;
    String betaTitle = Config.clientName + " Beta "+ "Revision: " + Config.Revision + " Made by: " + Config.developerName;
    String alphaTitle = Config.clientName + " Alpha "+ "Revision: " + Config.Revision + " Made by: " + Config.developerName;

    public GameFrame(GameShell rsapplet, int width, int height, boolean undecorative, boolean resizable) {
        rsApplet = rsapplet;
        //Config.ConfigLoad();
        if (Config.beta == 3){
            setTitle(alphaTitle);
        } else {
            setTitle(Config.beta == 1 ? title:betaTitle);
        }

        setIconImage(getToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(Signlink.findcachedir()+"/Sprites/Icons/icon.jpeg")));

//      //String imgURL = signlink.spritesLocation() + "this.jpg";
//      try {
//          setIconImage(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage());
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
        setUndecorated(undecorative);
        setResizable(resizable);
        setVisible(true);
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        setSize(width + insets.left + insets.right, height + insets.top + insets.bottom);//28
        setLocation((screenWidth - width) / 2, (screenHeight - height) / 2);
        setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.EMPTY_SET);
        setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.EMPTY_SET);
        requestFocus();
        toFront();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public int getFrameWidth() {
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        return getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
    }

    public int getFrameHeight() {
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        return getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    }

    public GameFrame(GameShell rsapplet, int width, int height) {
        this(rsapplet, width, height, false,false);
    }

    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        Graphics g = super.getGraphics();
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        g.translate(insets.left ,insets.top);
        return g;
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        rsApplet.update(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        rsApplet.paint(g);
    }

    private final GameShell rsApplet;
    public Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    public Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    public int screenWidth = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
    public int screenHeight = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
}
```

But I get this error when I run the client, what am I doing wrong?

> [CLIENT]: Client frame initialized...
>    Uncaught error fetching image:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
>     at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
>     at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
>     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
>     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)

Comment: The image doesn't exist where you think it does, but because I can't see what `Signlink.findcachedir()` is suppose to be, it's difficult to know what to recommend, but it looks like you're trying to use `getResource` to get a `File`...

Comment: the findcachedir leads to  > C:\Users\Kyle\.DivinationAlpha + \Sprites\Icons\icon.png

my icon is in > C:\Users\Kyle\.DivinationAlpha\Sprites\Icon\

and it still gives me the error

Comment: Then use a `File` reference, not `getResource` reference, it's not likely that the JVM will be able to resolve the path you've supplied within in it's concept of the class path...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using...

```
setIconImage(getToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(Signlink.findcachedir()+"/Sprites/Icons/icon.jpeg")));
```

Try using...

```
setIconImage(getToolkit().getImage(Signlink.findcachedir()+"/Sprites/Icons/icon.jpeg"));
```

Which will treat the `String` as file reference.  It is unlikely that the class loader can resolve the path you providing it.

You would also be better off trying to use `ImageIO` to read your images as it will throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong.

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

**Updated from comments**

```
BufferedImage image = null; 
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(Signlink.findcachedir()+"/Sprites/Icons/icon.jpeg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
frame.setIconImage(image);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: It loaded with no errors, the Java Icon and Toolbar haven't changed though

Comment: Did you use `ImageIO`?

Comment: `BufferedImage image = null;
  try {
   image = ImageIO.read(frame.getClass().getResource(Signlink.findcachedir()+">/Sprites/Icons/icon.jpeg"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  frame.setIconImage(image);
  frame.setVisible(true); `

like this? or am I doing it wrong

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I tried that too. Instead of the icons changing, a tiny blank window comes up, I get this error   

`[CLIENT]: Client frame initialized...
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at GameFrame.<init>(GameFrame.java:38)
 at GameFrame.<init>(GameFrame.java:78)
 at GameShell.createClientFrame(GameShell.java:60)
 at Client.main(Client.java:3760)
 at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:85)`

Comment: `getResource` will prefix the supplied value with the values from the `ClassLoader`'s classpath

Comment: Verify that the icon exists at `C:\Users\Kyle\.DivinationAlpha\Sprites\Icons\icon.jpeg`.  You can use `System.out.println(new File(Signlink.findcachedir()+"/Sprites/Ico‌ns/icon.jpeg").exists());` before the `ImageIO` call.  If it returns `false`, your image isn't where you think it is or it's not named what you think it is...